# What are the books that talk about the Area element of a surface?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Does someone know where I can find a good exposition  about area element of surface in $\mathbb{R} ^n$?

The Wikipedia has in this link:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_element

But I would like some book.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried Advanced Calculus by Wilfred Kaplan? I remember that this is a not too good book, but it has its advantages. For one more general approach I suggest Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres.

Comment: Thank you,  I'm  really grateful for the suggestions.